# Trying to make multiple divs that are scrolled to certain positions multiple triggers

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to achieve this but with my limited knowledge and chatgpt couldn't solve it.

Goal:
Multiple divs that hold long contents that needs to be scrolled, when page is loaded, all divs will be scrolled to certain positions. As all divs have different contents, scrolls are different.

Here's a sample with Figma
https://www.figma.com/proto/pTRoxhdX3MkT5A5ZHw1WPA/StackOverflow-Question?page-id=0%3A1&type=design&node-id=1-27&viewport=1194%2C529%2C1.2&t=Nb3hRH4d6spTln8C-1&scaling=min-zoom&starting-point-node-id=1%3A26&mode=design

What I have achieved:
I was able to create auto-scrolling with scroll event. Here's the sample code I created. It has both triggers, one with DOMContentLoaded and one with scroll.

```
// Function to reset scroll position for a specific scrollable element
function resetScrollPosition(scrollable) {
  const targetItemId = 'current'; 
  
  // Scroll to the target item within the scrollable element
  const targetItem = document.querySelector(`#${targetItemId}`);
  if (targetItem && scrollable.contains(targetItem)) {
    // Scroll to the target item if it's within the scrollable element
    targetItem.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center", inline: "nearest" });
  }
}
// Add scroll event listener to each scrollable element
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const scrollables = document.querySelectorAll('.scrollable');
  const timeouts = {}; // Object to store the timeout for each scrollable element
  
  scrollables.forEach(scrollable => {
    resetScrollPosition(scrollable);
    
    // Add scroll event listener to each scrollable element
    scrollable.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      // Log a message to the console to check if the scroll event listener is triggered
      
      // Clear the previous timeout for this scrollable element
      clearTimeout(timeouts[scrollable.id]);
      
      // Set a new timeout to reset scroll position after 5 seconds of inactivity
      timeouts[scrollable.id] = setTimeout(() => {
        resetScrollPosition(scrollable);
      }, 1000); // Adjust the timeout duration as needed
    });
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/haayany/n45Lbfd2/

However, as you can see in the title of the sample, the it does not move all divs' scrolls when it's loaded, but the first div only.

I was able to try it in a slightly different way, and this new one only moves the last one when the page is loaded.

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        const scrollables = document.querySelectorAll('.scrollable');
        const timeouts = {}; // Object to store the timeout for each scrollable element

        // Function to reset scroll position for a specific scrollable element
        function resetScrollPosition(scrollable) {
            // Replace 'targetItemId' with the ID of the item you want to scroll to
            const targetItemId = 'current';

            // Scroll to the target item within the scrollable element
            const targetItem = scrollable.querySelector(`#${targetItemId}`);
            if (targetItem) {
                // Scroll to the calculated position within the scrollable element
                targetItem.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center", inline: "nearest" });
            }
        }

        // Add scroll event listener to each scrollable element
        scrollables.forEach(scrollable => {
            scrollable.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
                // Clear the previous timeout for this scrollable element
                clearTimeout(timeouts[scrollable.id]);

                // Set a new timeout to reset scroll position after 5 seconds of inactivity
                timeouts[scrollable.id] = setTimeout(() => {
                    resetScrollPosition(scrollable);
                }, 5000); // Adjust the timeout duration as needed
            });
        });

        // Call resetScrollPosition for each scrollable element once DOM content is loaded
        scrollables.forEach(scrollable => {
            resetScrollPosition(scrollable);
        });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/haayany/0tmv4bkw/

I'm not sure how to update this properly to make it happen.

Comment: You use the same id for all of your div scrollable, can you change the id unique for each of the div @haayany

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const scrollables = document.querySelectorAll('.scrollable');
  scrollables.forEach((el) => {
    let current = el.querySelector('.current');
    el.scrollBy({
        top: current.offsetTop,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  })
});
```

```css
.scrollable {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Enable vertical scrolling */
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Styling for the scrollable div content */

.scrollable h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.scrollable p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <h2>Scrollable Div 2</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p style="color:red;" class="current">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <!-- Add more content as needed -->
</div>

<div class="scrollable">
  <h2>Scrollable Div 2</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p style="color:red;" class="current">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <!-- Add more content as needed -->
</div>

<div class="scrollable">
  <h2>Scrollable Div 2</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p style="color:red;" class="current">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <!-- Add more content as needed -->
</div>

<div class="scrollable">
  <h2>Scrollable Div 2</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p style="color:red;" class="current">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <!-- Add more content as needed -->
</div>
```

I think because the other element already in view. You can not use scrollIntoView. What I am thinking is to scroll each of the parent as much as the offset top of the current from it's parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Updated it using async. it starts from the last div, but I think that's fine...

```js
// Define an async function to handle scroll position reset
async function handleScrollPositionReset() {
  const scrollables = document.querySelectorAll('.scrollable');
  for (const scrollable of scrollables) {
    resetScrollPosition(scrollable);
  }
}

// Function to reset scroll position for a specific scrollable element
function resetScrollPosition(scrollable) {
  // Replace 'targetItemId' with the ID of the item you want to scroll to
  const targetItemId = 'current'; 
  
  // Scroll to the target item within the scrollable element
  const targetItem = scrollable.querySelector(`#${targetItemId}`);
  if (targetItem) {
    // Scroll to the calculated position within the scrollable element
    targetItem.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center", inline: "nearest" });
  }
}

// Add scroll event listener to each scrollable element
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
  const scrollables = document.querySelectorAll('.scrollable');
  scrollables.forEach(scrollable => {
    scrollable.addEventListener('scroll', async () => {
      clearTimeout(scrollable.timeout);
      scrollable.timeout = setTimeout(async () => {
        await handleScrollPositionReset();
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
  
  // Reset scroll position when the page is fully loaded
  await handleScrollPositionReset();
});

// Reset scroll position when the page is fully loaded
window.onload = async function() {
  await handleScrollPositionReset();
};
```

```css
.scrollable{
    width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto; /* Enable vertical scrolling */
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Styling for the scrollable div content */
.scrollable h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.scrollable p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

body{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollable1" class="scrollable">
  <h2>Scrollable Div 1</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p style="color:red;" id="current">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <!-- Add more content as needed -->
</div>

<div id="scrollable2" class="scrollable">
  <h2>Scrollable Div 2</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p style="color:red;" id="current">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <!-- Add more content as needed -->
</div>

<div id="scrollable3" class="scrollable">
  <h2>Scrollable Div 3</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p style="color:red;" id="current">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <!-- Add more content as needed -->
</div>

<div id="scrollable4" class="scrollable">
  <h2>Scrollable Div 4</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p style="color:red;" id="current">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum, justo at euismod mollis, tortor metus suscipit felis, ut volutpat ipsum velit ac orci.</p>
  <!-- Add more content as needed -->
</div>
```